# make post request with jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I need to submit a form from inside of colorbox iframe. For this, i tried setting data param alongwith href as suggested in docs, but it makes get request, not post. Also, ive tried making post request in jquery and then show data inside colorbox, but that doesnt give me the data inside of colorbox iframe.

I want this because we have a wizard-like flow where one screen connects the other and everything has to be sent through form submisions.

any suggestions?

thnx in advance ...

**Adding code**

```
$.colorbox({
            iframe:true,
            href:"/publisher/refer.html?action=viewReferAction&licenseCode=${param.licenseCode}",
            innerWidth:900,
            innerHeight:400,
            data:{"licenseCode":"${param.licenseCode}","referActionEId":"${chosenReferActionEId}"}
           });
```

The backend in JSP, hence extra curly braces.

Also, forgot to mention in question: "**the first window of this wizard-like flow comes on click of a button on the page**"

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Shared the code...any ideas...?

Comment: since you are sending the data via querystring, its obvious that the data will be posted through `GET`. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739570/posting-data-to-a-colorbox-iframe

Comment: set `iframe:false` and remove the `"` from the `data` values

Comment: @user1 : i belive that shouldn't be the case as its clearly mentioned in the docs that setting "data" param automatically make the request as POST. Also, Ive seen the code where it handles iteraction  with jquery. It is indeed using post, but for some reason, it ACTUALLY m akes get request. I know it doesnt make sense, but its happenning!

Comment: @spokey : done that already. no change!

Comment: @user1 setting `data` as an **object** makes it POST. `data: {value:'something'}` instead of `data:{'value':'something'}`

Comment: @user1: thnx for such prompt responses. Tried ur suggestion, but in-vain. May be im missing something other out. Anywayz, ive found a workaround and using it. Its working fine :) Thnx again...

Comment: @NitinBansal you can post your workaround below and mark it as answer for those looking for answer to similar questions

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

make a new backend code block that will return the actual form as plain html alongwith form's submit called automatically after form renderin is complete(use $.(document).ready() function).

Make sure to make that first request to this new block in an iframe as usual.

This is messy, but somves the problem :-)